# Nokogiri unescaped html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri

I am parsing HTML text using nokogiri and making some changes to that HTML.

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(html_code)
```

But i am using mustache with that html so the html contains mustache variables which are in enclosed in 
curly braces e.g.{{mustache_variable}}.

After tinkering with the nokogiri document, when i do

```
doc.to_html
```

These curly braces are escaped and i get something like `%7B%7Bmustache_variable%7D%7D`

---

But, not all of the content is escaped, e.g. if i have html as

```
<label> {{mustache_variable}} </label>
```

It returns, `<label> {{mustache_variable}} </label>`

---

But for html like, `<img src='{{mustache_variable}}'>`

It returns, `<img src='%7B%7Bmustache_variable%7D%7D'>`

So, i am currently doing a gsub to replace %7B and %7D with { and } respectively so mustache works.

So, is there a way i can get the exact html from nokogiri or a better solution ???

Comment: You're not really parsing HTML, you are parsing HTML templates, which is an important distinction. Nokogiri is doing the correct thing, but, to accomplish what you want you need to do something like @Sean Coleman recommends, and post process the output from Nokogiri.

Comment: Given this is an old question, has there been any movement on this?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need cgi module

```
require 'cgi'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(html_code)
CGI.unescapeHTML(doc.to_html)
```

or you can use [htmlentities lib](http://htmlentities.rubyforge.org/).

And try to use doc.content instead of doc.to_html

Comment: CGI.unescapeHTML(doc.to_html) and htmlentities both do not unescape the curly braces, i.e. it does not change %7B, %7D to {, } which is what i need.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem and ended up using a regular expression to convert the escaped double braces:

```
html_doc.gsub(/%7B%7B(.+?)%7D%7D/, '{{\1}}')
```

To make this safer, I'd recommend prefixing each mustache variable with a namespace, just in case some of the HTML does have the escaped double brace pattern intentionally, e.g.

```
html_doc.gsub(/%7B%7Bnamespace(.+?)%7D%7D/, '{{namespace\1}}')
```